# Region with block shows up in admin preview, but not on site

Tags: blocks, theming

I'm new to drupal and a bit confused by this. Using the standard Bartik theme (Drupal install 7.8) I see a search bar on the sidebar. Checking the Structure > Block it shows that the search is included in the Bartik theme on the sidebar. The preview while an admin shows the search.

However, as soon as I log out the entire sidebar_first region does not show. Just the content area.

EDIT: When adding a login box to the sidebar it does appear, however, the searchbar, and navigation do not. There are NO RESTRICTIONS applied.

EDIT2: View the screenshots below to see my settings.

Normal User sees:
[image]

Admin User sees:
[image]

Current settings for navigation block:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've to allow anonymous use to access the search form, to add this permission, you've to go People > Permission and search "Search" and check the box "Search content".

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work, plus according to the documentation: "If you select no roles, the block will be visible to all users."

Comment: The block gonna be available for everybody with the right to search in your site (anonymous include). By the way, have you indexed nodes ?

Comment: That's the problem, the block is NOT showing on the site. I want it to show for everyone, it is not showing for anonymous users, just for the admin. I have not indexed nodes, the site only has one page of content. I just want to set up the search bar first.

Comment: So the permissions worked for search, but not for navigation. See the images I've added.

Comment: he is not referring to the permissions on the block visibility, but the permissions for the ability to search in general. go to people > permissions and check of "search content"